# Content not displayed correctly

Tags: html, css

**EDIT:** here is a link to whats going on http://flameforged.altervista.org/games/gd/

I have 4 divs inside the `<main>` element I have styled them to display all on the same line straight across no matter what.

When I have lets say `<h3>Title</h3>` in all the divs they all display correctly still but once I add a little input field `<input type="text">` all the other divs appear to be moved down.

I am not sure how to fix the issue here is my css and html

```css
body{
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

header{
 background-color: #c0c0c0;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 border: 1px solid #c4bac4;
}

.nav-bar{
 display: inline;
    float: right;
}

.panel{
 display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 border: 1px solid #c4bac4;
    width: 24%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-left: 0%;
}
```

```html
    <main>
     <div class="panel" id="researchPanel">
         <h3>Research</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" id="typerPanel">
         <h3>HTML Terminal</h3>
         <form>
          <input type="text" class="typer" id="typer" placeholder="Type an HTML tag">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" id="employeePanel">
         <h3>Employees</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" id="upgradesPanel">
         <h3>Upgrades</h3>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Give `vertical-align: top` to panel. here is your working answer

```css
body{
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

header{
 background-color: #c0c0c0;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 border: 1px solid #c4bac4;
}

.nav-bar{
 display: inline;
    float: right;
}

.panel{
 display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 border: 1px solid #c4bac4;
    width: 24%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-left: 0%;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
    <main>
     <div class="panel" id="researchPanel">
         <h3>Research</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" id="typerPanel">
         <h3>HTML Terminal</h3>
         <form>
          <input type="text" class="typer" id="typer" placeholder="Type an HTML tag">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" id="employeePanel">
         <h3>Employees</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" id="upgradesPanel">
         <h3>Upgrades</h3>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: wow I spent 3 hours last night trying to fix it lol and it was that simple will accept when it lets me

Comment: It happens while coding..

Comment: all the time couldn't have chosen a better profession ^_^

Comment: @JoséphFlames This does not work on less wide screens ... check out the dupe link why and how to fix

Comment: I have different css and bootstrap which handles less wide screens